# A faster way to access Strikethrough on Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a document on Google Docs as a simple to do list.  I hate it that I have to access the Strikethrough command via a menu.

Is there a hidden keystroke to toggle Strikethrough or perhaps a way to add the Strikethrough command to the toolbar?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**For Windows / Linux:**
Select what you want to strike and click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

**For Mac:**
Select what you want to strike and click <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> shows other such keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: +1, this is THE solution, I think this should be the accepted answer (because the question was how to do it with a keyboard shortcut; not with using user scripts or extensions). By the way, here is a complete list of ***"Keyboard shortcuts for Google documents"***: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/179738?hl=en

Comment: Cmd + Shift + X does not work on my MacBook Pro and Google Chrome (April 2017). Does it work for anyone else?

Comment: ⌘+Shift+X works for me on El Capitan/Google Chrome 58 (June 2017). Both external keyboard and built-in MBP keyboard.

Comment: This initially did not work for me, because I had a chrome extension (PushBullet) already using this shortcut. To see all shortcuts used by extensions use ```chrome://extensions/shortcuts```. 
I had to scroll down, find the offending extension shortcut and click (X) next to it to disable ⌘+Shift+X being used for something else.

Comment: Note: on MacOS the alt-shift-x shortcut was being intercepted by the Chrome URL-Incrementer extension.  Clearing it from `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` did the trick.